# how to check programmatically whether the current installation of R is the newest one?

Tags: r, cran

How to check, from the level of R, if current installation of R is the newest one ? Finding version of installed R is easy part, but how to check what is the number of the newest version ? Is that kind of information available through CRAN ?

Comment: It's on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/). Are you asking how to check from within R?

Comment: @Thomas, yes  - how to check it within R ?

Answer (score 5):

A quick search in my favourite search engine found [this post by Yihui Xie](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2010-September/058588.html) which I turned into a function:

```
checkRversion <- function(){
  x = readLines("http://cran.r-project.org/sources.html")
  # the version number is in the next line of 'The latest release'
  rls = x[grep("latest release", x) + 1L]
  newver = gsub("(.*R-|\\.tar\\.gz.*)", "", rls)
  oldver = paste(getRversion(), collapse = ".")
  # new version available?
  message("Installed version: ", oldver)
  message("Latest version: ", newver)
  compareVersion(newver, oldver)
}
```

In use:

```
checkRversion()

Installed version: 3.0.1
Latest version: 3.0.1
[1] 0
```

Comment: It's also listed in R-FAQs: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.txt after the phrase "The current released version is ".

Answer (score 3):

You can use approach from [`gtools`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtools/gtools.pdf).

The code is similar to that in Andrie's answer, but uses the `/src/base/R` folder explicitly - rather than `sources.html` file, so it's potentially more robust because relies on the actual binaries being present.

A small problem is, `gtools` hardcoded the folder name, so "as is" their code is wrong - but I quite like the idea, so I updated it to iterate through the available CRAN urls and find the latest one:

```
checkRVersion <- function (quiet = FALSE) 
{
    baseUrl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-"
    majorVersion <- 3
    repeat {
        url <- paste(baseUrl, majorVersion, sep = "")
        if (url.exists(url)) {
            majorVersion <- majorVersion + 1
        }
        else {
            break
        }
    }

    url <- paste(baseUrl, (majorVersion-1), sep = "")
    page <- scan(file = url, what = "", quiet = TRUE)
    matches <- grep("R-[0-9]\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+", page, value = TRUE)
    versionList <- gsub("^.*R-([0-9].[0-9]+.[0-9]+).*$", "\\1", matches)
    versionList <- numeric_version(versionList)

    if (max(versionList) > getRversion()) {
        if (!quiet) {
            cat("A newer version of R is now available: ")
            cat(as.character(max(versionList)))
            cat("\n")
        }
        invisible(max(versionList))
    }
    else {
        if (!quiet) {
            cat("The latest version of R is installed: ")
            cat(as.character(max(versionList)))
            cat("\n")
        }
        invisible(NULL)
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch! Then parsing `sources.html` less hassle - I'd keep my answer just in case someone comes across `gtools` here..

Comment: From `library(RCurl)`, you could also do `url.exists("http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3")` and `url.exists("http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-4")`, etc. until you got a `FALSE`.

Comment: I meant that you could build that into your code to make it flexible across major releases (check if the next major release exists, if not, get the most recent minor release).

Comment: Makes sense - I updated the answer, looks more flexible now :)